# Expect an array of float numbers to be close to another array in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, arrays, floating-point, jasmine

I'm testing a Javascript function returning an array of numbers, to see if the returned array contains the same elements as the array containing the expected output:

```
expect(myArray).toEqual(expectedArray);
```

This works flawlessly if myArray and expectedArray only contain integers, but fail if there is at least one float present, due to floating-point precision errors. `toBeCloseTo` does not seem to function on arrays.

Currently I'm doing a loop to to do member-wise checking:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    expect(myArray[i]).toBeCloseTo(expectedArray[i]);
}
```

... but is there a cleaner way to do this? If the test fails for whatever reason, the output is bloated with a *hideous* amount of error messages.

Comment: Check out `toBeCloseTo` it appears to do what you want.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the [ArrayContaining](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/asymmetric_equality/ArrayContaining.js) matcher, adapt the loop and create your own matcher.

Answer (score 13):

The following code should answer your question:

```
function expectToBeCloseToArray(actual, expected) {
  expect(actual.length).toBe(expected.length)
  actual.forEach((x, i) =>
    expect(x).withContext(`[${i}]`).toBeCloseTo(expected[i])
  )
}
```

Comment: Any difference between `actual.forEach((x, i) => expect(x).toBeCloseTo(expected[i]))`? I think `forEach` might be slightly faster since it doesn't expect a return value (it's faster than a `map` for sure). The execution will stop at the first fail anyway, because it throws.

Comment: `toBeCloseTo` returns undefined (at least in Jasmine 3.5) so `forEach` is needed here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for (let i=0; i<returnedArray.length; i++){
  if(expectedArray.indexOf(returnedArray[i]) === -1 ){
      console.log("not a match")
      break;
  }else{
      console.log("it's a match")
      break;
  }
}
```